# install pear on WAMP

Tags: php, pear

I tried to install pear

WAMPserver 2.1
OS : win 7

steps I followed from following link
http://chadash.tumblr.com/post/1515528654/how-to-install-php5-pear-lib-on-windows-7

I get a copy of go-pear.phar from http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar url.

Following is the output

```
Are you installing a system-wide PEAR or a local copy?
(system|local) [system] : system

Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\tmp

 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\tmp

 4. Binaries directory                            : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\pea
r
 6. Documentation directory                       : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\doc
s
 7. Data directory                                : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\dat
a
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\cfg

 9. Public Web Files directory                    : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\www

10. Tests directory                               : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\tes
ts
11. Name of configuration file                    : C:\Windows\pear.ini
12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : .

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
'".\php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

*WARNING*
We found php.exe under ., it uses an unknown SAPI. PEAR commandline
tool has not been tested with it, if you have a CLI (or CGI) php.exe available,
we strongly recommend using it.

Beginning install...
Configuration written to C:\Windows\pear.ini...
Initialized registry...
Preparing to install...
installing phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarbal
ls/Archive_Tar-1.3.7.tar...
installing phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarbal
ls/Console_Getopt-1.3.0.tar...
installing phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarbal
ls/PEAR-1.9.3.tar...
installing phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarbal
ls/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tar...
installing phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarbal
ls/XML_Util-1.2.1.tar...
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/
go-pear.phar/System.php on line 302

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pe
ar.phar/System.php on line 302
ERROR: file \Archive_Tar-1.3.7\Archive\Tar.php does not exist
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/
go-pear.phar/System.php on line 302

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pe
ar.phar/System.php on line 302
ERROR: file \Console_Getopt-1.3.0\Console\Getopt.php does not exist
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/
go-pear.phar/System.php on line 302

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pe
ar.phar/System.php on line 302
ERROR: file \Structures_Graph-1.0.4\docs\html\media\banner.css does not exist
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/
go-pear.phar/System.php on line 302

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pe
ar.phar/System.php on line 302
ERROR: file \XML_Util-1.2.1\examples\example.php does not exist
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/
go-pear.phar/System.php on line 302

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/PEAR/go-pe
ar.phar/System.php on line 302
ERROR: file \PEAR-1.9.3\OS\Guess.php does not exist

** WARNING! Old version found at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3, please remove it or b
e sure to use the new c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\pear.bat command

The 'pear' command is now at your service at c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\pear.bat

** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use 'c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\pear.bat' until you have added
** 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3' to your PATH environment variable.

Run it without parameters to see the available actions, try 'pear list'
to see what packages are installed, or 'pear help' for help.

For more information about PEAR, see:

  http://pear.php.net/faq.php
  http://pear.php.net/manual/

Thanks for using go-pear!

* WINDOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES *
For convenience, a REG file is available under C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3PEAR_ENV.
reg .
This file creates ENV variables for the current user.

Double-click this file to add it to the current user registry.

Press any key to continue . . .

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3>
```

pear command is still not recognized by the system.

```
*WARNING*
We found php.exe under ., it uses an unknown SAPI. PEAR commandline
tool has not been tested with it, if you have a CLI (or CGI) php.exe available,
we strongly recommend using it.
```

There are no such message the author receive. I updated the environmental var and php is running as cli.

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: Enter: 12, than insert the path to your php.exe file: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3`. Then continue.

Comment: Something wrong,.... Warning related to php.exe is not there but it didn't worked I am still getting those mkdir() warning..

Comment: I suggest you first remove everything PEAR first and then re-install it from scratch. Normally it just runs flawlessly. The mkdir commands are using the wrong path(s) and PEAR itself notifies you that an older version is installed. You should only install on a clean system, otherwise uninstall first.

Answer (score 2):

```
12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : .

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
'".\php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

You need to specify the **full** path to the php.exe file, including `php.exe`. "." alone is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for the same thing but installing in XAMPP: [Error installing go-pear.phar in Windows 10 with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134934/error-installing-go-pear-phar-in-windows-10-with-xampp)

When you're prompted with

```
1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
```

I think you need to enter

```
12
```

Then a pop up browser appears, allowing you to select the folder where php.exe is in your WAMP installation (do a search in Windows if you're not sure), then continue the PEAR installation.